# can I get 'thumb_pdf' using Slack's files.upload method?

Tags: pdf, attachment, slack

while testing Slack API's [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload)
I found that I can not get a PDF with thumbnail attached.

I want is following(I got this using Slack official client):
[image: PDF file in slack with thumbnail]

but this is what I got using files.upload API.
[image: PDF no thumbnail]

so I compared the result of [channels.history](https://api.slack.com/methods/channels.history)
[image: thumb_pdf]

you can find 'thumb_pdf', 'thumb_pdf_w', 'thumb_pdf_h' on the left (uploaded using official client). does anyone know how can this be done with slack's API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether this is useful for you. So please think of this as one of several answers.

In my environment, I also confirmed the same situation with you. When PDF is uploaded using [files.upload](https://api.slack.com/methods/files.upload) API, the thumbnail is not attached. On the other hand, when PDF is uploaded using the official client (I uploaded it using my browser.), the thumbnail is attached. In the case of images, I can see the thumbnail for both patterns.

### Analysis :

I have assumed that when the PDF is uploaded using the official client, the special parameters and endpoints may be used. The files are uploaded by `multipart/form-data`. So I analysed the request when the PDF file is uploaded. I used the chrome developer tools. As a result, it was found that the special endpoint and access token are used for this situation.

- `https://upload.slack.com/api/files.uploadAsync` is used as the endpoint.

  - At `files.upload`, `https://slack.com/api/files.upload` is used.
- `xoxp-############-############-############-##########` is used as the access token. (`#` is used instead of numbers.) This is the difference from the legacy token and access token retrieved by OAuth2.

  - The legacy token and access token retrieved by OAuth2 are `xoxp-############-############-############-################################`.

These are used for not only PDF files, but also other files.

### Experiment :

As an experiment, I tried the request using the endpoint and access token retrieved by analysing the request. I used curl for this. The curl command is as follows.

```
curl \
     -F file=@sample.pdf" \
     -F channels=### channel ID ### \
     -F token=xoxp-############-############-############-########## \
     -F filename=sample.pdf \
     -F title="Upload test" \
     "https://upload.slack.com/api/files.uploadAsync"
```

### Results :

When the curl command mentioned above is used, `{"ok":true,"ticket":"#####","file":"### file ID ###"}` is returned. And the PDF with the thumbnail could be seen at the timeline. If the legacy token and access token retrieved by OAuth2 are used for this endpoint, `{"ok":false,"error":"not_allowed_token_type"}` is returned. From this, it is found that `xoxp-############-############-############-##########` is the special token.

### Note :

- This method may be not general. Also I don't know whether this is suitable for this situation.
- The expiration time of access token is not clear.

If this information is not useful for you, I'm sorry.

Comment: Great answer and many thanks to your effort. seems there's no way to do it stably. BTW, can you share information which tool did you use to reverse engineered those?

Comment: @behumble There are some uncertain information for the access token and endpoint. So it may be difficult for other clients to use. For this, I want to expect that Slack API or options for APIs will be added in the future. About Chrome DevTools, you can see it at [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/?hl=en). In the case of your question, I have used the Network panel in the DevTools. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.